# No Result is displayed after click on dynamic database

Tags: php, mysql

Here i m unable to get data from database. I want result as when i click on category the result should be from product database where `c_id`= category from database[image] 
Here the displayed menu is from my database table name=category
when on click i should get the result to right side of the page as coin selector=(results related to coin selector from products table).
My database table of category is
[image]
database table of product table is
[image]

```
<?php    
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "admin_login");
     include 'header.php';
    ?>  
     <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-2">
                 <div class='panel panel-default'>
                     <?php 
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM category";  
                        $res = mysqli_query($link, $query);  
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))  
                        {  
                             ?>
                         <div class='nav nav pills nav-stacked nav_custom'>
                         <li><a href='category.php?id=<?php echo $row['c_id']; ?>'><?php echo $row['c_name']; ?></a></li>
                     </div>
                             <?php
                        }  
                     ?>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class='col-lg-6'>
                 <div class="panel panel-info">
                                <div class="panel panel-body">
                                    <?php
                                    $c_id = $row["c_id"];
                                    $query = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE c_id='.$c_id.' ";  
                                    $res = mysqli_query($link, $query);  
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))  
          {  ?>
              <div class="col-lg-3">  
              <div class="panel panel-info">  
              <div class="panel-heading"><?php $row["product_name"]; ?> 
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body"> 
          <center> 
              <img src="image/product_image/'<?php echo $row["product_img"]; ?>'" alt="'<?php $row["product_name"]; ?> '" class="img-responsive" width="200px" height="200px">
              </center> 
          </div> 
              <div class="panel-footer">           
              <a href="product_details.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-block btn-xs">Details           
              </a>
              <a href="contact.php?id=<?php $row["id"]; ?> " class="btn btn-info btn-block btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></span>&nbsp;Request Sample Quote           
              </a>
              </div>  
              </div>  
              </div> 
          <?php } ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
      <p><br></p>
     <p><br></p>
     <p><br></p>
    <?php
    include 'footer.php';
    ?>
```

Comment: it's because you are over-writing your `variables` in both query and loop iteration, which causes error actually.As well as first loop is closed too early and in `$c_id = $row["c_id"];` `$row["c_id"]` is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> NO its not variable overwriting issue

you have syntax error in your query.AND NO its not overwriting issue.the issue you are passing the variable `id`  for displaying product
see here

```
<li><a href='category.php?id=<?php echo $row['c_id']; ?>'>
```

and you are trying to fetch the product with `$c_id` which is not exist.see here

```
<div class="panel panel-body">
<?php
$c_id = $row["c_id"];
query = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE c_id='.$c_id.' ";  
$res = mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

then you need to do access the `id` like this

```
    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $c_id = $_GET['id'];
       $query = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE c_id='$c_id' ";  
       $res = mysqli_query($link, $query); 
      //your `while` loop 
    }
```

Remember your query is open to sql injection attack use `prepared statement`

full code

```
<?php    
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "admin_login");
include 'header.php';
?>  
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-2">
<div class='panel panel-default'>
<?php 
$query = "SELECT * FROM category";  
$res = mysqli_query($link, $query);  
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){ ?>
    <div class='nav nav pills nav-stacked nav_custom'>
    <li><a href="category.php?id=<?php echo $row['c_id']; ?>">
    <?php echo $row['c_name']; ?></a></li>
    </div>
    <?php
}  
?>
</div>
</div>
<div class='col-lg-6'>
<div class="panel panel-info">
<div class="panel panel-body">
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $c_id = $_GET['id'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE c_id='$c_id' ";  
    $res = mysqli_query($link, $query);  
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {  ?>
        <div class="col-lg-3">  
        <div class="panel panel-info">  
        <div class="panel-heading"><?php $row["product_name"]; ?> 
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body"> 
        <center> 
        <img src="image/product_image/'<?php echo $row["product_img"]; ?>'" alt="'<?php $row["product_name"]; ?> '" class="img-responsive" width="200px" height="200px">
        </center> 
        </div> 
        <div class="panel-footer">           
        <a href="product_details.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-block btn-xs">Details           
        </a>
        <a href="contact.php?id=<?php $row["id"]; ?> " class="btn btn-info btn-block btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></span>&nbsp;Request Sample Quote           
        </a>
        </div>  
        </div>  
        </div> 
    <?php } 
} ?> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<p><br></p>
<p><br></p>
<p><br></p>
<?php
include 'footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: Thank You So Much for your help.

Comment: glad to help you